# Line below headings alignment issue

Tags: css

I have created a heading style with a line below heading.The issue is the line does not align itself with the alignment of text to center or right. It's always on the left side no matter where the text is aligned.

```
h1 {
margin: 0 0 25px;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
color:black;
    line-height:2em;


}
h1:after {
content:' ';
position: relative;
display:block;
width: 40px;
margin: 0 0;
border:1px solid #CB9033;
border-radius:4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);

}
```

Comment: Can you create a live example of the problem?

Comment: Or at the very least a screenshot of the problem and on which browser... you aught to help us help you.

Comment: You made the pseudo element `display:block`, so it doesn’t get affected by `text-align` on the element itself. Make it `inline-block` instead, if that’s what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `class` for center and right alignment:

```css
h1 {
  color:#000;
  font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight:300;
  line-height:2em;
  margin:0 0 25px;
  position:relative;
}

h1:after {
  border:1px solid #CB9033;
  content:'';
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  position:absolute;
  width:40px;
}

h1.right {
  text-align:right;
}
h1.right:after {
  right:0;
}
h1.center {
  text-align:center;
}
h1.center:after {
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="right">Test</h1>
<h1 class="center">Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
```